# Return results of a request loop

Tags: node.js

I want to make an initial request to get a list of IDs, and then make a request for each individual id and store the JSON results in an array. Here is the code basics:

```
request(options, function(err, resp, body){
 ids = (JSON.parse(body))[ids];
 results=[];
 for(id in ids){
  options.path='/api/example/' + ids[id];
  request(options, function(err, resp, body){
   results.push(JSON.parse(body));
  })
 }
 res.send(results);
})
```

When I run this, results is still an empty array and when I put res.send(results) in the inner request function,it only captures one result and not all of them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most NodeJS operations are asynchronous. If some function requires a *callback* it means that there's no guarantee that after invoking it you'll get the result.

When you perform N requests using the `for` loop you're starting N asynchronous operations and each one's callback will be called when the underlying asynchronous operation has ended.

There're many options here to solve the issue.

For example, [you can use Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), a [Promise pattern](https://www.promisejs.org/) implementation, to enqueue async promises and wait untill all have been resolved:

```
request(options, function(err, resp, body){
 // First of all, you create a deferred object
 var deferred = Q.defer();

 // Also, you create an array to push promises
 var promises = [];

 ids = (JSON.parse(body))[ids];
 results=[];
 for(id in ids){
  options.path='/api/example/' + ids[id];

  // You create a promise reference, and later
  // you add it to the promise array
  var promise = deferred.promise;
  promises.push(promise);

  request(options, function(err, resp, body){
   results.push(JSON.parse(body));

   // whenever an async operation ends, you resolve its promise
   deferred.resolve();
  })
 }

 // Now you wait to get all promises resolved (i.e. *done*), and then your 
 // "results" array will be filled with the expected results!
 Q.all(promises).then(function() {
     res.send(results);
 });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! When i tried this, it gave me a TypeError: Object [object Promise] has no method 'resolve'.

Comment: @Keroles It's `deferred.resolve()`, sorry. I've updated the code snippet in the answer itself.

Comment: That worked, I also moved the last portion (Q.all...) outside the main request (along with deferred and promises vars) and it seems to work most of the time (The inconsistency might be with the api I'm working with) Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Keroles Nice! Actually, an async function should return a promise, so any one can be continued using promises. Good luck! ;)